# flutter dependency not downloading

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, dependencies

i open my old project in android studio and when i run the command

```
flutter pub get
```

it searching the dependencies on https://pub.langdart.org instead of https://pub.dev and giving the errors as.
`Running "flutter pub get" in infixedu...
Because infixedu depends on table_calender any which doesn't exist (could not find package table_calender at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...

Because infixedu depends on table_calender any which doesn't exist (could not find package table_calender at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...

Because infixedu depends on table_calender any which doesn't exist (could not find package table_calender at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...
`

Answer (score 0):

The package table_calender is removed from the https://pub.dev.
It could be any reason why the author decided to pull the package, but That's the reason why your `flutter pub get` is failing.

Also if you are from Bangladesh, I see a lot of GitHub issues raised on the same topic. The solution is to use VPN apparently.

Comment: no i am from india and my android studio is not serching the dependencies at https://pub.dev it is searching the dependencies on https://dartlang.org which does not exisit

Comment: Can you tell me the package name? 

https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar Is this the one?